# Is the Borg Collective limited to bipeds?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, borg

How does the Borg deal with non bipedal sentient lifeforms? Are there any who have been assimilated into the Borg Collective?

Comment: Species 8472 is not biped, but then again, assimilation failed for other reasons..

Comment: Not canon, but in William Shatner's novel The Return there is a Borg dog

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Other than the Species 8472 comment I made, I've found 2 candidates and one interesting note:

- [Species 259](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_259) were "omnicordial lifeforms" that the Borg assimilated [automatic regeneration sequencers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Autonomous_regeneration_sequencer) from.  This species is from a [transmaterial energy plane](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transmaterial_energy_plane) that the Borg called [Galactic Cluster 3](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galactic_Cluster_3).  Nothing else about their physiology seems to be known.
- [Species 5973](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_5973) are "multispectrum particle lifeforms".  No mention is made of them actually being assimilated.  The Kazon were likewise known to the Borg as Species 329, however, the Kazon were deemed unworthy and not assimilated - so simply having a designation does not indicate the Borg would assimilate that species.

The [Greech](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Greech) are this thing:

[image: Greech parasite]

In the Voyager novel [Unworthy](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Unworthy), they, along with the Neyser (humanoid), the Dulaph (sphere-shaped silicon-based species), the Irks (a bio-mimetic species), a moth-like species, and a noncorporeal species, created the [Indign](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Indign) cooperative in an attempt to mimic the Borg, when the Borg considered them unworthy for assimilation.

So in the novels at least, it seems possible (although unlikely) for non-humanoids to be assimilated.  However, given that the Borg Queen is humanoid, it could well be that the Borg idea of perfection includes humanoids.  Their attempted assimilation of Species 8472 would then be explained as an attempt to gain knowledge of their biology in order to adapt it to the humanoid shape.

So, **No, the Borg are not limited to bipeds if "omnicordial lifeforms" are not bipeds - and even if they are, it is unlikely they are limited since they did at least try to assimilate the 3-legged Species 8472**

Comment: I assume its 6 legged species 8472.  But it is worth noting that species 8472 have the ability to morph into humanoid shape as noted in TNG Season 5, Episode 4 "In the Flesh"

Comment: @ Richard Vivian, You mean Voyager not TNG!

Answer (score 5):

Assimilation will require fitting into the Borg structure.  I.e able to use regeneration alcoves etc, the assimilation process of non-bipedal life forms could just use the head and torso of the the individual assimilated and replace a quadrupedal or hexapedal limb system with a mechanical bi-pedal limb system.  As is the case with the Borg Queen.  Having not seen her original form, she may not have been a biped.

Comment: If (the natural form of) a species contributed significantly toward the Borg's goal of perfection, I think they would be able to overlook the relatively minor inconvenience of adapting some of their technology to work for a non-bipedaled species. After all, I think it's safe to assume that e.g. the alcoves themselves have no intristic requirement that the regeneration cycle is performed standing upright. That said, surely not needing to adapt their technology would hardly be a downside.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's such a waste of time, standing up and sitting down..  ;)

Comment: An old answer, but it's worth noting in *Q Who?* that Data observes each regeneration alcove is adapted to a specific individual. So, at least that particular Borg structure has some evidence that it would be uniquely built to allow for non-humanoid use if necessary.